# Php Mail Send to all admin users in mysqli

Tags: php, email, mysqli

Hey i have issue with mail system. I would send to all admin users en email but it just takes the first one and the others not

```
$adminUsers = User::getAdminUsers();
    foreach($adminUsers as $adminUser){
        $to  = $adminUser->getEmail(); 
        // sujet
        $subject = 'Boîte à idées - Nouvelle idée';

        // message
        $user = new User($userId);
        $link = "http://idees.pcprofi.ch/pages/login.php";
        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Une nouvelle idée proposée</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>Bonjour,</p>
          <p>
            Une nouvelle idée a été proposée par ' . $user->getName() . ' '
                . '. Vous pourrez la consulter une fois connecté à la '
                . '<a href="' . $link . '">Boîte à idées</a>.
          </p>
          <p> 
            Salutations.
          </p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';

        // nécessaire pour un mail HTML
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        // informations additionnels
        $headers .= "To: " .  $adminUser->getName(); " \r\n";
        $headers .= " " . $adminUser->getEmail(); "\r\n";
        $headers .= ' From: Boîte à idée <bai@test.com>' . "\r\n";

        // Envoi du mail
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

And my function to get the admin users is this .

```
public static function getAdminUsers(){
    $db = new Database();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnect();
    $statement = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `admin`= 1";
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $statement);
    $users = [];

    while($result = (mysqli_fetch_array($sql))){
        $id = $result['id'];
        $user = new User($id);
        $users[] = $user;
    }
    return $users;
}
```

Thanks allready in advance. I hope you know how to help me :)

Comment: `var_dump($adminUsers)` shows how many records?

Comment: @violator667 it gives me array(3) with all admins

Comment: OK so it isn't this. There is something important after `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`? I cant see the end of the foreach, maybe you use `break`, `exit`, `die` somewhere

Comment: @violator667 yeah exit that i can test the var_dumps

Comment: If you have `exit` inside `foreach` you will never loop through entire array

Comment: Yeah i just saw ty a lot if u want post an answer i'll give u right and vote up  THanks dude :)

Comment: that's OK - I'm glad I could help.